# search for rows in Sharepoint list

Tags: search

As a Sharepoint user, I would like to have a way to do a simple search in a list and have returned the rows which match my condition.

I know you can filter with the selectors, but I am talking about searching for a string in all fields without having to browse all the values in all the columns.

Is there anything OOB or I have to write some custom code ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use search with a 'This List' scope. That should do it. However, the results will not be presented in a 'list-like' format. If you want to do that, then you'd have to modify your search results page (editing the core results web part, mainly the XSL), and set up search 'managed properties' for each column on the list.

The detail of how you'd do all that depends a lot on how you've implemented Search on your system...

Comment: Thanks Andy, I will try that, but I have also to filter by content type, otherwise in the results I'd get other views, and it's quite confusing for the user. In my tests I also was unable to search by values im multi-row fields. I'd also prefer to have the results appear in the same order as in the list. I saw on the net that there are client solutions using jQuery, but these have the problem that work only on the current page.

Comment: Filtering by content type - or 'content class' (a slightly different option in a search experience) is feasible. I blogged about that http://www.novolocus.com/2008/06/26/content-classes-and-search/  I've searched multi-value fields without issue, so I'm not sure what's happening there for you. And sort order could be tricky without more extensive customisation.

Comment: Yes, you are right, multi-line ARE indexed, probably I pasted some extra chars in the field. I'll set this question as answered and ask my fellow programmer to help me with the XSL, hoping in the next version of SP...